# python urwid.Terminal - enable scrolling

Tags: python, urwid

I'm trying to execute linux commands/shell scripts and showing the output in python urwid based console.

When I use subprocess and append output to text box widget using threading:

ADVANTAGES:

- it displays the output runtime as expected.
- up/down scroll is possible with arrow keys

ISSUES:

- It displays non-ascii characters in the output - meant for clearing screen or colors etc.

When urwid Terminal is used:

ADVANTAGES:

- it displays the output runtime as expected.
- The output text is neat and clean - no weird characters displayed - colors seen nicely in the output text.

ISSUES:

- Unable to scroll up when the screen limit is exceeded while showing the output.
- executing command with "cmd | less" can enable scrolling, but again the non-ascii characters get displayed there which is not desired.

Is there any way by which we can enable scrolling with up/down arrow keys in urwid.Terminal widget?
Please help.

Comment: `less` will by default render non-printable characters (such as those used to do terminal escapes, likes colors) as black-on-white. You can have less pass them through to the terminal with `less -R`, or by typing `-R` in `less` itself.

Comment: thanks a lot ... i can get the things going now with less -R option ... :)

Comment: Haven't tried it, but pageUp/pageDown should scroll it according to the [source](http://excess.org/urwid/browser/urwid/vterm.py) or bind `MyTerm.term.scroll_buffer(...)`